# Variable reset to default option, WHY?

Tags: javascript, customization

I do not understand how I keep ending up with "null" after variable is assigned a number.

```
function evalKayScript(syn){
    coms = extract(syn,"{...}");
    document.write(JSON.stringify(coms));//debug
    for(x in coms){
        ops = extract(coms[x],"(...)");
        com = null; //<-- ***com preset null***
        for(y in funNames){
            if(ops[1] == funNames[y]){
                com = y; //<-- ***com changed to "y"***
            }
        }
        alert(com); <-- alerts given below (first two alerts)
        if(com == null){
            alert("Command ((("+ops[1]+"))) Not Registered!");
            return null;
        }
        exe = funValues[y];
        inputs = execVars(ops[2]);
        inputs = extract(inputs,"[...]");
        for(y in inputs){
            exe.replace(new RegExp("/\(\%"+y+"\%\)/gim"),inputs[y]);
        }
        exe.replace(new RegExp("/\(\%name\%\)/gim"),ops[0]).replace(new RegExp("/\(\%function\%\)/gim"),ops[1]);
        exea = exe;
        if(exe.replace(new RegExp("/\:\:\:javascript/gim"),"")! = exes){ //<-- new invalid ":" error
            eval(exe);
        }else{
            evalKayScript(exe);
        }
    }
}
```

I do not understand why, variable "com" goes to a number, then back to null...
I have setup some error catching in my own form, and i end up with these alerts:

```
0 //<-- var com
null //<-- ***var com? this makes no sense, how does it go back to null?***
Command ((("(%name%) already exists!"))) Not Registered! //<--caused by if(com == null) This is normal.
```

Live script at http://jstone88.bugs3.com/kayscript/file1.html, and JS file at http://jstone88.bugs3.com/kayscript/kayscript.js

Comment: It looks like there's just no matching `funNames[y]` the second time through the loop.

Comment: `com = null;` sets `com` to `null` *in each iteration*. Your problem isn't clear to me.

Comment: ? but that doesn't make sense, there is only one preset function in funNames, there is definitely something missing that I am not seeing, and @Felix King, it is only supposed to go through once, because i am entering, `{(output)(custom)([document.write(\"(%0%)\");][:::javascript])}` . and the `com = null;` is set before the loop that assigns it a new value.

Comment: So you are saying that `coms` only contains one property? Are you 100% sure about that?

Comment: Yes, @Amit Joki gave me a fix, all I have now is an invalid ":".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You aren't using `RegExp` constructor as it should have been used.

It is like this:

```
new RegExp("pattern without / at the beginning an end","flags");
```

`/pattern/flags` is literal form of writing a regex in js, but it is different in RegExp constructor.

Comment: Thank you, the RegExp was wrong in my initial script, not i have usual problems, that caused me to use RegExp, it says there is an invalid ":".

Comment: what was your original regex?

Comment: `/\:\:\:javascript/gim` @Amit Joki

Comment: you don't need to escape `:`. Just use `:::javascript/gim`

Comment: Still saying invalid ":". @Amit Joki

Comment: Sorry the regex should have been this:  `/:::javascript/gim`

Comment: i did, without the RegExp command, exactly `/:::javascript/gim` and `new RegExp(":::javascript","gim")` @Amit Joki

Comment: Wow, I was looking at the wrong area... it says the invalid ":" is in the `eval(exe);` command :/

Comment: I got it, thank you sooooooo much for your help. no more errors. Just a problem with adding new commands to funNames :) Im sure i can possibly fix it @Amit Joki

Comment: glad to have helped you ;)